# Ignite repeat execute

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I send request in Ignite Client and client execute task on Ignite servers in cluster. Server need calculate some data from cache and return response to client. Client use IgniteCompute for execute, but if server was lost (crashed, connect lost, timeout) Ignite not balance this task for execute another server.

My question
Can Ignite repair (repeat) execute if connection lost with server in cluster? Or i need check this errors in client  myself and send repeat request ?

I found some properties :

setAckTimeout

setSocketTimeout

setNetworkTimeout

setDiscoverySpi

setFailureDetectionTimeout

setClientFailureDetectionTimeout

setRebalanceTimeout

But it is not work....

My stack

- Java 1.8
- SpringBoot 2.4.5
- Ignite 2.10

Answer (score 2):

Ignite supports failover in terms of jobs. In order to achieve that you need to configure `FailoverSPI`. More information could be found in the [documentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/distributed-computing/fault-tolerance).